# Makefile only actually applied changes in main.cpp while all compiled

Tags: makefile

The title might be confusing, but that's what happened...

Here's my Makefile.

```
all:mystdio libmystdio.a main.o myscanf.o myprintf.o
    
mystdio: main.o libmystdio.a
    clang++ -o mystdio main.o -L. -lmystdio -Wall -g -std=c++17
libmystdio.a: myscanf.o myprintf.o
    ar cr libmystdio.a myprintf.o myscanf.o
main.o: main.cpp mystdio.hpp
    clang++ -c main.cpp -Wall -g -std=c++17
myscanf.o: myscanf.cpp mystdio.hpp utilities.hpp
    clang++ -c myscanf.cpp -Wall -g -std=c++17
myprintf.o: myprintf.cpp mystdio.hpp utilities.hpp
    clang++ -c myprintf.cpp -Wall -g -std=c++17
clean:
    rm -rf mystdio *.o *.a *.a
```

When I made changes in `myscanf.cpp` or `myprintf.cpp` and then make file, the output showed that it had been compiled and `mystdio` is updated. But actually nothing happened.

For example, let's assume I add `printf(":)\n");` at the beginning of a function in `myscanf.cpp`. Then I call the function in `main.cpp`. After making file, output in the terminal tells me that `myscanf.o` and related files were recompiled. But when the program runs, no `:)` is outputed.

However, when I add `printf(":)\n");` in the main function and make file, it was outputed. This did confuse me. I wonder how can I solve it.

command used:

```
make && ./mystdio
```

When I changed something in `myprintf.cpp` and make again, here's output from the terminal.

```
clang++ -c myprintf.cpp -Wall -g -std=c++17
ar cr libmystdio.a myprintf.o myscanf.o
clang++ -o mystdio main.o -L. -lmystdio -Wall -g -std=c++17
```

By the way, if I use `make clean` before `make && ./mystdio`, it'll work correctly, but of course that's not what "make" is designed for...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Files were recompiled. Were they also linked into an updated `mystdio`?

Comment: Please cut and paste the make command you invoked and the output it generated.

Comment: You should add "s" to the ar command: "ar crs ..."

Comment: @Andreas well that's not the case, I think. My project is so small that there's no need adding "s" . Anyway, that's what I was told.

Comment: @Jens output generated implyed that they were linked, but acctually that made no difference.